# Firefox and IE displaying the same thing differently

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Before i start, i know that IE handles code differently,
I have a small + sign that is floated left but it makes the table cell taller in IE but stays in the correct place in Firefox and Chrome.

Heres and image of what is happening:

[image: Firefox left, IE right]

Heres the HTML:

```
<tr>
              <td align="left" class="menutext" id="nav-products"><img id="signProducts" border="0" src="/images/menu/sign.gif" /><a href="/products/index.asp"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Products</strong></a></td>
            </tr>
```

And the CSS:

```
#signProducts {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    float: left;
    /* [disabled]padding-right:0px; */
    top: 7px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I added it into the CSS of #signproducts but there was no change at all

Comment: tried using line-height?